# Using SQLCipher with Mono for Android

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, xamarin.android, sqlcipher

Does anyone have any tutorials on how to setup SQLCipher for Mono for android in visual studio 2010?

If so could you share it with me and possibly show how you would create and connect to an encrypted SQLite database including Connection String?

Answer (score 1):

We've put together a tutorial on using our new SQLCipher binaries targeting Mono for Andoroid [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-on-mono-for-android).  The main difference is the article shows integration with MonoDevelop.